# Rails: Difference between timezones in hours

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, time, timezone

I'd like to be able to say `user1 is 4 hours ahead of user2`, calculated based on the time zones the users specify in their account.

Using the following code:

```
time1 = Time.zone.now.in_time_zone(user1.time_zone)
time2 = Time.zone.now.in_time_zone(user2.time_zone)

distance_of_time_in_words time1,time2
```

...gives a difference of `less than a minute` - similarly subtracting the two times gives `0`. Rails obviously still sees these two times as the same.

Any idea how I can calculate this difference between two time zones?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you take your `time1` instance and call `utc_offset` on it, you will get the amount of time offset from UTC in seconds. Combine this with the `utc_offset` of `time2`, throw in some subtraction, and you should get the time difference in seconds. From there you can do the conversation to whatever unit of time you like.

```
irb(main):020:0> time1 = Time.zone.now.in_time_zone("EST")
=> Sun, 09 Jun 2013 07:11:46 EST -05:00 
irb(main):021:0> time2 = Time.zone.now.in_time_zone("MST")
=> Sun, 09 Jun 2013 05:11:49 MST -07:00
irb(main):022:0> time_difference_in_seconds = time2.utc_offset - time1.utc_offset
=> -7200
irb(main):025:0> (time_difference_in_seconds/60/60).abs
=> 2
```

Comment: Be careful about the actual zone you pass in.  If you use abbreviations like "EST" and "MST" - you are ignoring daylight saving time.  You should use a full rails zone id, like "Eastern Time (US & Canada)".

Comment: Also, don't forget that the difference will be highly dependent on the exact value of `now`, so don't save this result and assume these two zones will always be X hours apart.  Run it every time you need it - and perhaps pass in the date/time in question, rather than relying on `now`.  See [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=84aWtseb2-4) especially the part starting at 3:57.